# Create grouping variable in dataframe when a variable is increasing

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following sample data.frame

```
data.frame(V1=rep(1:5,times=5))
```

I would like to create another variable which separate my observations in groups and the rule should be that whenever `V1` is increasing, observations are part of the same group.

So the outcome should be:

```
data.frame(V1=rep(1:5,times=5),V2=rep(1:5,each=5))
```

The only solutions I was thinking about so far are not really efficient, anyone else has an hint about how to do it without for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
 with(d1, ave(V1, V1, FUN= seq_along))
```

Or

```
with(d1, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(V1)<0)))
```

As the @Laterow mentioned in the comments, `<0` could be replaced by `<1` so that only increasing values will be grouped.

Comment: I think it should be `<1`, as only increasing values should be grouped.

Comment: True, but not when `d1[5,1] <- 4` :) "(...) the rule should be that whenever `V1` is increasing, observations are part of the same group."

Comment: For my purposes they are always increasing, so it doesn't really make a difference. But thank you for consideration anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  My connection was patchy.  So, couldn't reply soon.